# MongoDB GroupBy child Array but Sum parent

Tags: arrays, mongodb, group-by, sum

Suppose I have:

```
[
{ProjectId: "1", PriceSold: 100, Item: {Name: "Package1", Specs: ["A", "B"]} } ,
{ProjectId: "2", PriceSold: 500, Item: {Name: "Package10", Specs: ["A", "C"]} } ,
{ProjectId: "3", PriceSold: 900, Item: {Name: "Package100", Specs: ["D", "E"]} } ,
{ProjectId: "4", PriceSold: 50, Item: {Name: "Package90", Specs: ["F"]} } ,
]
```

I would like to do a GroupBy Specs but sum the parent PriceSold. The result would be:

```
[
{Spec: "A", Total: 600},
{Spec: "B", Total: 100},
{Spec: "C", Total: 500},
{Spec: "D", Total: 900},
{Spec: "E", Total: 900},
{Spec: "F", Total: 50},
]
```

Any Aggregation that I try returns me groups of Specs and not the item and the sum does not work. First try:

```
db.ClientProject.aggregate([

{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$Item.Specs", "__agg0" : { "$sum" : "$PriceSold" } } }, 

{ "$project" : { "GroupId" : "$_id", "GroupSum" : "$__agg0", "_id" : 0 } }

])
```

Second try (It counts correctly, but I cant do the sum of PriceSold)

```
db.ClientProject.aggregate([

{ "$unwind" : "$Item.Specs" }, 

{ "$project" : { "Specs" : "$Item.Specs", "_id" : 0 } }, 

{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$Specs", "__agg0" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }, 

{ "$project" : { "GroupId" : "$_id", "GroupSum" : "$__agg0", "_id" : 0 } }])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
db.ClientProject.aggregate([{$project : {PriceSold: 1, 'Item.Specs':1}}, {$unwind : '$Item.Specs'},
{$group : {_id : '$Item.Specs', Total: {$sum : '$PriceSold'}}}])
```

**Note:** In general using `$unwind` on entire collection is not that efficient, it would be a good idea using it on small dataset maybe after filtering collection (like after `$match`), So as we don't have that option here, at least using `$project` to make the document to have less fields to work on.

Comment: The good thing about your answers is that you believe in providing the optimized query.

Comment: @srinivazy the array is comming correct, but the sum is not working... returns 0 for every result...

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR : It's working for me - with the provided sample, did you check the field name(also type of it's value is Number) in your DB matches with this query ?